# Saving my LZ77 tags in the decompressed file for n java

Tags: java, algorithm, compression, computer-science

I implemented LZ77 algorithm in java and actually it works and outputs the tags correctly in the form <pos, len, next>. But I don't know how to save those tags in a file such that the total size of the file get lesser than the original one.

I tried to convert the tags to binary and save them to the file, but actually the file size got bigger.

Can anyone explain an algorithm to save the tags into the file?

Comment: In LZ77, the format of saved data will like to be (position, length, character). What does next mean here in you ```<pos, len, next>```? Is it mean next character?

Answer (score 1):

The LZ77 specification doesn't indicate the encoding of the triples.  If you look at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78, the "implementation" section shows how various implementations have output the triplets.

You are free to use one of these or implement your own.